# JsTree: Load custom metadata from an external xml source

Tags: xml, serialization, data-structures, jstree, xbel

I have an existing data structure which is stored as an xml doc.  It is essentially a sitemap.  Every node has some associated metadata (e.g., keywords and description associated with the node).  I would like to be able to use the xml_data plugin to be able to load directly from that source.  From a quick look at both the documentation and the source, it doesn't look like that is possible - I'm limited to the two formats described in the documentation.

However, I can't imagine that this is a completely unique use case.  It seems like my options would be to extend jstree so that I could add my own XSLT to the xsl var to handle my format, preprocess the format of the file server side so that the result is in the expected format, or change my data interchange format to JSON and convert between JSON and XML serverside.  The sense I get from the posts I have seen is that it is at least possible to serialize/deserialize metadata with the json_data plugin, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Can anyone help refine my direction based on your experience?

Answer (score 4):

I looks to me that it is possible.

> See:
>
> http://www.jstree.com/documentation/xml_data
>
> The JsTree function called .parse_xml
>   can be used to convert XML strings or
>   objects to the DOM structure required
>   by jstree.

Edit: **Wrong!**

If you post an example of your site map XML I'd be happy to create a working example for you.

Edit: **Working example below**

You can make JsTree process an external XML source but via the **ajax** options.  Imagine you had an XBEL file like this:

```
<xbel version="1.0">    
    <bookmark href="http://stackoverflow.com">
        <title>Stack Overflow</title>
    </bookmark>
    <folder>
        <title>Stack Exchange</title>
        <folder>
            <title>Programming</title>
            <bookmark href="http://stackoverflow.com">
                <title>Stack Overflow</title>
            </bookmark>
            <bookmark href="http://stackapps.com">
                <title>Stack Apps</title>
            </bookmark>
            <bookmark href="http://webapps.stackexchange.com">
                <title>Web Applications</title>
            </bookmark>
            <bookmark href="http://programmers.stackexchange.com/">
                <title>Programmers</title>
            </bookmark>
        </folder>
        <folder>
            <title>Systems</title>
            <bookmark href="http://serverfault.com">
                <title>Server Fault</title>
            </bookmark>
            <bookmark href="http://superuser.com">
                <title>Super User</title>
            </bookmark>
        </folder>
        <bookmark href="http://careers.stackoverflow.com">
            <title>Careers</title>
        </bookmark>
        <bookmark href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com">
            <title>Meta</title>
        </bookmark>
        <bookmark href="http://area51.stackexchange.com">
            <title>Area 51</title>
        </bookmark>
        <bookmark href="http://gaming.stackexchange.com">
            <title>Gaming</title>
        </bookmark>
    </folder>
</xbel>
```

You can process this with JsTree like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function () {
                $("#xbel").jstree({
                    "xml_data" : {
                        "ajax" : {
                            "url" : "stackexchange.xml",
                            "success" : function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                                var result = $('<dom></dom>');
                                var root = $('<root></root>');          
                                var doc = traverseXbel($(data), root);
                                result.append(doc);
                                return result.html();
                            }
                        },
                        "xsl" : "nest"
                    },
                    "plugins" : [ "themes", "xml_data" ]
                });

            });

           function traverseXbel(xbel, doc){
                var title, href, item, name, content, innerdoc;
                // folder => item
                // bookmark => item with href attribute

                // Deal with this level bookmarks                
                $(xbel).children('bookmark').each(function(){
                    href = $(this).attr('href');
                    title = $(this).find('title').text();
                    if(title && href){
                        item = $('<item></item>');
                        content = $('<content></content>');
                        name = $('<name></name>');
                        name.attr("href", href);                        
                        name.text(title);                        
                        content.append(name);
                        item.append(content);                        
                        doc.append(item);
                    }
                });                
                $(xbel).children('folder').each(function(){
                    title = $(this).find('title:first').text();
                    if(title){
                        item = $('<item></item>');
                        content = $('<content></content>');
                        name = $('<name></name>');
                        name.text(title);                        
                        content.append(name);
                        item.append(content);                        
                        item = traverseXbel($(this), item);
                        doc.append(item);                            
                    }
                });                
                return doc;
           }


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="xbel"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Okay I feel less of an idiot now, my first answer was wrong because I misunderstood the JsTree API docs.

Answer (score 0):

The following jsTree with custom XML example might be useful: [JSTree and custom XML](http://uimonster.com/wiki/index.php?title=JSTree_and_custom_XML)

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same requirement as you where my source XML was not following either one of the "formats" described in jsTree. The way I solved this problem was by writing a XSLT script to transform my XML to a format that jsTree accepts and then asynchronously loading the resulting XML file.

Comment: Could you please post your code.. atleast sample of it please?